# Ubuntu 18.04 live usb installer crashes at keyboard selection

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I wanted to try dual booting my hp laptop with Ubuntu, so I downloaded the 18.04 iso, flashed it to an 8gb flash drive, and booted into it. My laptop's bios is on UEFI, and I disabled secure boot and fast startup.

However in the installer, after I select continue in the keyboard selection step, the cursor starts spinning and after a bit the entire system becomes completely unresponsive. I tried Ubuntu 20.04, and it freezes at boot. I've also tried using legacy support in my Bios, setting nomodeset in GRUB, and multiple flash drives, but it's the same result every single time.

Comment: Can you confirm what tool you used to flash the ISO, and what occurs *if* you disconnect the Keyboard up until that section, does it freeze? Is it *just* the GUI? Can you spawn a TTY session?

Comment: I used balenaEtcher, it's on my laptop with an integrated keyboard, and a TTY session also becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I found that adding ahci=off in grub managed to fix the problem and let me boot in ubuntu 20, but now it's unable to find my windows drive. My laptop has a 250 gb nvme ssd if that helps.